# Access Properties Defined in Logback programmatically

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have an administration console I'm building, and I want to display the logs created in `Logback` for my application.  However, where those logs are stored is different per environment.  I have several property files that define where the logs are stored:

```
<configuration>
  <property resource='log.properties'/>
  <property resource='log.${ENV:-prod}.properties'/>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${log.dir}/sync.log</file>
  ...
</configuration>
```

I'd like to find the value of `${log.dir}` from `Logback's` Java API.  I'd tried the following, but it doesn't have any of the properties defined in the resources.  For example:

```
 LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
 String logDir = loggerContext.getProperty("log.dir"); // this always returns null
```

So my question is what API should I be using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, properties are defined in "local" [scope](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#scopes). However, you can force a property to have context scope, in which case it's pretty easy to get the value of the property:

```
 LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
 String val = lc.getProperty(aString);
```

Defining properties in "context" scope is considered a little heavy handed. Instead of defining all/many properties in context scope, you could define only a single property in context scope. Here is an example:

```
<configuration>
  <!-- get many props from a file -->
  <property resource='log.properties'/>
  <-- set only one to be in context scope -->
  <property scope="context" name="log.dir.ctx" value="${log.dir}" />
  ...
</configuration>
```

You could then obtain the value you are looking for with:

```
 LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
 String val = lc.getProperty("log.dir.ctx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties are also defined in `LoggerContextVO`, you can get your defined properties like this:

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
LoggerContextVO loggerContextRemoteView = context.getLoggerContextRemoteView();
Map<String, String> propertyMap = loggerContextRemoteView.getPropertyMap();
String loggingFile = propertyMap.get("log.dir.ctx");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use a Spring property defined in *application.properties* when configuring a custom Encoder programmatically. In the Encoder it would have to decide whether to manipulate the log or not. This feature could be toggled on or off by a configurable parameter.

Since this logging library would be used by many different projects, each deployment could configure their needs with this property from their own *application.property* file.

I solved it like this:

You can access spring properties defined in *application.properties* from logback.xml.

```
<configuration>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="ourCustomParameter" source="eu.some.property.name" />
...
</configuration>
```

Note the declaration of scope. We need to be able to retrieve this variable from Context in Java code.

In Logback you can get it from Context now. Writing a custom Encoder you can access it like this

```
this.getContext().getProperty("ourCustomParameter");
```

Or a larger example:

```
public class CustomLoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder extends LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder {
  
  ...
  
  @Override
  public byte[] encode(ILoggingEvent iLoggingEvent) {
    return super.encode(iLoggingEvent);
  }
  
  ...
  
  private String getOurSpringProp() {
    return this.getContext().getProperty("");
    // Note that this will return null if this property does not exist
  }
}
```